# Eagerly update a keras model's weights directly using the gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a custom optimizer with Eager Execution in Ternsorflow 1.15 but can't figure out how to update the weights.
Taking gradient descent as an example, I have the weights, the gradient and a scalar learning rate but can't figure out how to combine them.

This is an implementation of gradient descent where model is a `keras.Model` e.g. a multilayer CNN:

```
lr = tf.constant(0.01)

def minimize(model, inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(input)
        loss_value = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=targets)

    grad = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
    step = tf.multiply(self.lr, grad)
    model.trainable_variables.assign_sub(step)
```

but it fails on the `tf.multiply` saying

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [5,5,1,6] != values[1].shape = [6] [Op:Pack] name: packed`

I also know the last line will fail as `trainable_variables` is a list and doesn't have the method `assign_sub`.

---

How can I rewrite the last two lines of my code to do:

```
model.trainable_variables -= lr * grad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. As both are lists we need to iterate through their pairs of gradients and variables for each layer together and update each of these separately.

```
lr = tf.constant(0.01)

def minimize(model, inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(input)
        loss_value = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=targets)

    grad = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
    for v, g in zip(model.trainable_variables, grad):
        v.assign_sub(lr * g)
```